Calculate the angle between a surface and a curve

The curve $\gamma$ is given by $x = t$, $y = t^2$, $z = 2t^3$ and
intersects the surface $\Sigma$ defined by $z = x^2 + 3y^2 - 2xy$.
Find the angle between $\gamma$ and $\Sigma$ at their intersection
point.

I have found the intersection points $(0,0,0), (1,1,2), (\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{9},\dfrac{2}{27})$.
At the point $(1,1,2)$, the targent vector to $\gamma$ is $(1,2,6)$ and the normal vector to $\Sigma$ is $(0,-4,1)$. I want to ask what is the formula to calculate the angle between $\gamma$ and $\Sigma$

The question refers to "their intersection point." As you correctly have pointed out, there are in fact three intersection points. The question is lacking in specificity ... along with the overriding issue of what the angle between a line and a plane ought to be. See my answer for this.

You should have been a bit more explicit with your question. I'm assuming (and others have commented/answered) that you know how to use the dot product to find the angle between two nonzero vectors.
What is your course/text defining as the angle between a line and a plane? I would not take it to be the angle $\theta$ between the direction vector of the line and the normal vector of the plane. Rather, I would take it to be the complement $\pi/2-\theta$ of that angle.
If you consider the angles between a nonzero vector $v$ and all the vectors $w$ lying in a plane (through the origin), the smallest such angle will be with a vector $w$ in the direction of the projection of $v$ onto the plane. If you draw the right triangle defining this projection, you'll see that this smallest angle is, in fact, the complement of the angle $v$ makes with the normal vector of the plane. (There are two choices of unit normal. I'm taking the one on the same side of the plane as $v$.)

so the angle $\theta$ between a curve and a surface satisfies $\sin\theta=\dfrac{v_1.v_2}{|v_1|.|v_2|},v_1$  is the targent line of the curve at the intersection point and $v_2$ is the normal line of the surface at the intersection point, right?

Yes, I would say so, choosing $0\le \theta\le\pi/2$.

I assume that the curve and the plane are in $\mathbb{R^3}$. In this case, cannot you use the dot product to find cosine of an angle between vectors? 
If $u, v$ are vectors, then $$\cos \theta = \frac{<u,\,v>}{|u|\cdot |v|},$$ where $<.,\,.>$ denotes tthe dot product and $|\,|$ is a length of vector.
